# How do I add/update a table variable row based on a DB row in MS SQL loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a table variable and then select rows from an MS SQL DB table and then do the following:

- loop thru each row
- add or update the table variable row, depending on the looped row column values

Here's how the code more or less be structured

```
 select * from table1 t1
 define @table variable --this should have corresponding columns with the same types in t1

 --loop thru each t1 row
 --check if the combination of row values in t1 is present
 --if present update @table column
 --else, insert the t1 row into @table

 loop each t1 row
     select * from @table where @table.c1=t1.c1 and @table.c2=t1.c2 and @table.c3=t1.c3
     if @table @numrows >= 1 
         update @table.c4=t1.c4 where @table.c1=t1.c1 and @table.c2=t1.c2 and @table.c3=t1.c3
     else
         insert into @table(c1, c2, c3, c4) values (t1.c1, t1.c2, t2.c3, t1.c4)
```

Comment: Why do you want to loop at all? SQL is a set based language, so you should be using a set based solution. Iterative processes are terribly slow in SQL.

Comment: Hi  @Larnu
, I already have a query that uses outer apply to get only 1 related join record. But the query takes way too long to execute compared to my initial query that gets all related join records. I figured going back to the initial query and doing some sort of "compress"

Comment: *"But the query takes way too long to execute"* Changing that query to be a loop would likely make it exponentially slower. If you have a slow performing set based query, then that is what you should be asking about.

Comment: I would copy the record set in MS Excel and have the procedural language JavaScript loop through each row and do the "compress". This is why I thought of doing something similar

Comment: "That is not likely to be an improvement but sometimes you need to try something. It will be a good learning experience if nothing else" @SMor that's a push in the right direction! Thanks for the encouragement, much obliged :-)

Comment: Would you post some sample data, before and after the update - what the criteria is and what you hope to achieve might help?

Comment: How about you give us the existing set-base query and we'll see what we can do with it? To be honest, it looks like you want a `MERGE`, and knowing what indexes you have would also help.